# Broken zip when downloading from sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I have to download about 200GB of data from a Microsoft 365 sharepoint site on a Mac. The downloaded zip files seem to be broken.

[image]

I have tried downloading smaller folder and fewer set of files at a time etc. I have also tried three different browsers: Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Occasionally they work, but most zips do not work. Just searching around, it seems like this issue have been mentioned many times for many years, but I cannot find any solutions.

Is there any solution to make this work?

UPDATE:

I tried on a linux machine just to ensure it's not a Mac specific issue. I tried OneDrive but that wouldn't work. I also posted this question on a [sitepoint specific stackexchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308912/broken-zip-when-downloading-from-sharepoint-site), but nothing helpful came out of it. Finally, I downloaded individual files or a few files at a time. It took several hours but it worked.

Comment: What are you downloading with? Try JDownloader [freeware]

Comment: What browser are you using? When it comes to downloads and microsoft, I often find that I need Edge for this to work (and firefox also usually works). There is an edge browser for macos too.

Comment: I've tried safari, firefox and chrome. I couldn't find edge on app store.

Comment: Perhaps, and this may come as a shock, the zip file is broken.

Comment: No shit sherlock

Comment: I had a similar problem. Eventually I copied a direct link my browser (Vivaldi) was using, fed it to `wget` and only then I managed to download the desired file in its entirety. It may have been a coincidence, but my try with `wget` was the first one that fully succeeded after several attempts with the browser had given me incomplete files.

Comment: Browsers are notorious for breaking large downloads [although should be better these days with https than http], hence my JDownloader suggestion.

Comment: Browser downloads are notoriously undependable. A download manager or utility is almost mandatory for large downloads, by preference one that can restart interrupted downloads.

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski for the wget suggestion, but unfortunately the link is not openly accessible. It doesn't even have a password. It is behind a multifactor authentication.

Comment: Regarding large files, downloading from Dropbox or Box seem to work fine through the browser. Why is it that Sharepoint has to be so difficult?

Comment: @mindlessgreen With the browser's Developer Tools you can get a full URL that works with curl or wget and includes session information so that you can use it outside the browser

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use wget, another is to synch via onedrive app.